# Player object changes position when I click the pause button

Tags: unity, c#, input, unity-ui

I have a simple mobile game where every time I touch the screen, the car changes direction.

The thing is, I need to implement a pause button, but when I click pause I need the car to stay still and not move. Right now it keeps responding to the inputs even when the game is frozen. Could someone help me find a way to overcome this issue?

Here's what happens:

[image: Animated gif showing car changing direction when Pause is clicked]

This is how I check for input and change direction:

```
void CheckInput()
{
   
    if (firstInput)
    {
        firstInput = false;           
        return;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && firstInput == false)
    {
        ChangeDirection();
    }
}

void ChangeDirection()
{
    if (movingLeft)
    {
        movingLeft = false;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 270, 0);
    } else
    {
        movingLeft = true;
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 180, 0);
    }
}
```

And how I pause my game:

```
public void PauseButton()
{
    if(isPaused == false)
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0f;
        //_pauseButton.SetActive(false);
        //_pauseButton.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = reload;
       
        Debug.Log("Clicou");
        isPaused = true;
    } 
}
```

I tried to check the "isPaused" bool on the character controller, but even like this it moves the first time I click. I tried to use a Raycast like I read in a few places, but I couldn't get it working.

Comment: So the problem is that clicking on the pause button is causing the car to change direction or the problem is that even if the game is paused, you can still change direction of the car with clicking?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this methods when pressing the pause button (im assuming that you added a button for that):

```
bool gameIsPaused = false;
void PauseGame ()
    {
       if(!gameIsPaused )
       {
         Time.timeScale = 0;
         gameIsPaused = true;
       }
        Time.timeScale = 0;
       else
       ResumeGame();
    }
void ResumeGame ()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        gameIsPause = false;
    }
```

Comment: Still face the same problem, on the first click on the pause button the player moves =[

Comment: just check if the game is paused while calling the method ChangeDirection();
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && firstInput == false && !gameIsPaused)

Comment: Same thing, on the first click it will change the car position before the gameIsPaused change its boolean value

Comment: That comes from execution order then, you have two options here: